# Format timeval into "best units"

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I am trying to write a benchmark program that takes about 20 minutes to complete because the actual functions need to be called at least 50 times.

I used the following code:

```
struct timeval start, end;
long mtime, seconds, useconds;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
usleep(2000);
gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
seconds =end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
useconds=end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec; 
(mtime>1000)?cout<<"elapsed time in seconds:"<<setprecision(8)<<mtime/1000<<"seconds\n":cout<<"elapsed time in milliseconds: "<<setprecision(3)<<mtime<<" milliseconds\n";
```

but I am required to write it in such a way that the output deduces the best units to use for the elapsed time and displays the results in those units. any suggestions how I can revise the above code for the requirement? thx!

Comment: Can you be more specific about "best unit"?

Comment: Boy this sounds like homework.

Comment: This is nothing to do with "benchmarking code", you simply want to "format time into appropriate units".  Perhaps you could adjust your question title?

Comment: `std::string humanreadable_time(long t)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your "best unit" requirement is basically "human usable units."  If so, take the time and

- millisecs **mod** 1000 gives number of milliseconds
- millisecs **div** 1000 gives seconds (where **div** is integer division)
- seconds **mod** 60 gives number of seconds
- seconds **div** 60 gives minutes

and so on.

Comment: thx Charlie, unfortunately this is not homework ;-(...sounds like I am on the right track and need to just convert these into human usable/readable units....

Comment: @Oli, I have no idea where to change the question title....will try to figure it out...

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do it yourself.  Put it in a function, and carry it with you always.  You'll use it again, I assure you.